# How to make a variable fixed permanently in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In unsafe environment, I know that by using the `fixed` statement, I can obtain and pin the address of a variable so that I can safely work with the acquired pointer. However, is there any way to safely store this pointer somewhere? As in, make that variable fixed permanently until the pointer itself is disposed.

For example, what should I do if I want a pointer to an `integer`/`float`/`double` to be a member of my unsafe class?

Comment: What is this for? the web? forms? Can you explain more what you want to achieve with code

Comment: @CR41G14 That maybe should have formed part of the question but the tags make it pretty clear.

Comment: It's probably wise to allocate such objects the old-fashioned way, and keep them out of the managed view. Pinning managed objects complicates matters for the garbage collector, so permanently pinning them is even worse.

Comment: It's just general C#. I just finished reading this article about the fixed statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx that inside a fixed block, I can be assured that the pointer I'm holding will point to the correct object. However, it will only work inside the fixed block. What I want to do is permanently prevent the system from moving some objects around, not just inside a small block of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More permanent solution for pinning memory is to use `GCHandle` class, like this:

```
var handle = GCHandle.Create(myObject, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr address = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
//... use it
handle.Free();
```

this allows you to retrieve an address of pinned object and prevents GC from moving it around. However, you have to keep your `GCHandle` alive and free it once you are done. This is much easier to span over many methods or even classes then using `fixed()` block.

It's worth to note though, that pinning memory may hurt your performance, because you are making `GC`s work harder.

If you need a chunk of memory which will never be moved, because you are using it to inter operate with native code etc. you might consider using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` so that you will allocate non movable memory which will not interfere with `GC`.

Comment: If myObject (your first parameter in the Create method) is of value type, will the address obtained be the address of that object, or will it be the address of a copy of that object? And how can I access the underlying object through the IntPtr? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that myObject can be a value type, if you will pass a struct object, it will be boxed because GCHandle takes an object parameter. What do you mean by undelying object? You have a reference to your object already, because you have pinned it. However, if you are sure how data is layed out in your class, you can access it by getting a pointer and moving it by an offset. For example, for arrays, when you get a pointer from AddOfPinnedObject() it will point to the first element, so you can access arrays elements using pointers that way.

Comment: So if I have a value type variable that's already allocated and I don't want it to be moved around, can I use the GCHandle to do the job?

Comment: @IcySnow And how this variable is allocated? Because if it's a value type variable which you have created on stack (it's a local variable) you have a guarantee that it will not be moved. If it's a field in an other class object, you have to pin, but not the struct itself, but the object (which is a class) which contains it. Then, there's a problem of knowing at which offset the struct is inside the object, and if you need to know that, read about StructLayout and FieldOffset attributes.

Comment: So if I pin the object, which is of reference type, and obtain the unsafe pointer to one of its value-type member, then I can safely work with that pointer without worrying about the system moving my object somewhere else, right?

Comment: @IcySnow - yes, but you have to be smart about getting this pointer to value type. Even if you have a class which has only 1 value type inside, you have no guarantee that this value type will be accessible at offset 0, to make sure that your class is layed out just like you like, you need to explicitly set fields offsets. It's best for you to check out few examples on msdn regarding native interop and GCHandle itself, there are few examples which tell you how to pass various objects to native code (and doing that requires exactly the same thing as you require - so that memory will not be moved

Comment: If I acquire the pointer in a way similar to this: int* p = &SomeClass.SomeIntMember and not through field offset, there won't be any problem right?

Comment: @IcySnow - Please try to write that, if SomeClass is a class, you can not take it memory by &, so no, it won't work like that. It's not c++. Comment-discussion like this will not solve your problem and it will make it harder for others to know the solution. Try to progress from where you are now and once you get another problem, ask another question please.